# problem with react router dom v6 subroutes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am doing a practice exercise and I am creating sub-routes with react router dom v6, the problem I have is that the profile route has an authentication if it is authenticated it shows me the profile component otherwise it sends me to home, now to this /profile route I created a /exerciselist subroute but when I want to access /profile/exerciselist the component does not load me, it sends me directly to the /profile route, how can I make it load the profile/exerciselist route?

```
import React  from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Navigate} from "react-router-dom"
import { useContext } from "react"
import { authContext } from "./context/authContext"
import Homepage from "./pages/Homepage"
import Login from "./pages/Login"
import Register from "./pages/Register"
import Notfound from "./pages/Notfound"
import Profile from "./pages/Profile"
import Footer from "./components/footer"
import ExercisesList from './components/exercises_list'
import "./public/css/appStyles/appStyles.css"

function App() {

  const { auth } = useContext(authContext)

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={!auth.auth ? <Homepage/> : <Navigate to="/profile" replace />}/>
        <Route path="/register" element={ !auth.auth ? <Register/> : <Navigate to="/profile" replace />}/>
        <Route path="/login" element={ !auth.auth ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/profile" replace /> } />
        <Route path="/profile/*" element={ auth.auth ? <Profile />  : <Navigate to="/" replace /> } >
          <Route path="exerciselist" element={<ExercisesList/>} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<Notfound/>}/>
      </Routes>

      <Footer/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

When rendering nested routes you have a couple options.

1. Render an `Outlet` component in the parent route's component for the nested `Route` components to be rendered into.

   Example:

   ```
   import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

   ...

   const Profile = () => {
     ...
     return (
       <>
         ... Profile component JSX ...
         <Outlet />
       </>
     );
   };
   ```

   Remove the trailing `"*"` since the nested route is rendered into `Outlet`.

   ```
   <Route
     path="/profile"
     element={ auth.auth ? <Profile /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />}
   >
     <Route path="exerciselist" element={<ExercisesList/>} />
   </Route>
   ```
2. Render a `Routes` and nested `Route` components directly in the routed component.

   ```
   import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

   ...

   const Profile = () => {
     ...
     return (
       <>
         ... Profile component JSX ...
         <Routes>
           <Route path="exerciselist" element={<ExercisesList/>} />
         </Routes>
       </>
     );
   };
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <Route
     path="/profile/*" // <-- trailing * allows matching nested routes
     element={ auth.auth ? <Profile /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />}
   />
   ```